# Open new Fragment from FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmenttransaction

I have MainActivity that extends `FragmentActivity` and I also have ConnectionListFragment that contains List of connection ID's. And when user tap on connection ID I want to open new `LogFragment` (that extends `Fragment`) and give more details about that connection. But the problem is that when user select connection ID fragment never show's. Here's my code
My `MainActiviy`

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LogTextUpdater, LogDetail{

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private static int id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        UiFragment.setLog(this);
        ConnectionListFragment.setLogDetail(this);

        initialisePaging();
    }

    private void initialisePaging() {
        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, UiFragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ConnectionListFragment.class.getName()));
        mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateText(String sender) {
        //LogFragment.readFromDatabase(sender);
        ConnectionListFragment.updateList();

        Toast.makeText(this, sender, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void startFragment(String connectionID) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Start " + connectionID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        LogFragment logFrag = new LogFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        logFrag.setConnectionID(connectionID);
        ft.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, logFrag);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

my main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here's my ConnectionListFragment

```
public class ConnectionListFragment extends Fragment{

    private static SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static SQLiteOpenHelper helper;
    private static Context context;
    private static ListView listView;
    private static SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    private static LogDetail logDetail;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity();

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.connection_list, null,
                new String[]{Constants.SESSION_ID}, new int[]{R.id.connectID}, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connection_list, container, false);
    }

    public static void setLogDetail(LogDetail logTextUpdater){
        logDetail = logTextUpdater;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedID = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.connectID)).getText().toString();
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), selectedID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                logDetail.startFragment(selectedID);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void updateList(){
        new ConnectionListID().execute();
    }

    public static class ConnectionListID extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
            helper = new Database(context);
            db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
            return db.query(true, Constants.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"_id", Constants.SESSION_ID},
                    null, null, Constants.SESSION_ID, null, null, null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
            super.onPostExecute(cursor);

            adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

So what can be wrong with my code. I guarantee that `startFragment` method is called when user tap on one of the list item because I see Toast on my device.

Comment: viewpager has a `fill_parent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, the container is of height 0px, so it is not visible.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px" />
```

From your usage, I would suggest you to create a new Activity with only this FrameLayout, with height `match_parent` to contain your LogFragment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between FragmentActivity and Activity except support for lower OS versions for fragment.

Fragment can be used as component in activity. 
To start a new fragment means you should replace existing fragment with new fragment

Fragment is not like activity So, you can't start new fragment as new activity.